# Alternative to jQuery UI rotate method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using a theme which uses jQuery UI rotate method, but after updating to the newer version it has stopped working. I have found out that the jQuery UI has removed the rotate method, and I can use some extension if I want to keep it working. But I was wondering if its possible to use some alternative function for the following line, since its so simple:

```
$("#slider").tabs("rotate",0,true);
```

The purpose is to rotate the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement the extension as suggested by the docs, you would use the extension like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs().tabs("rotate", 4000, true);
```

note the extra call to `.tabs()`

Here is the extension: https://github.com/cmcculloh/jQuery-UI-Tabs-Rotate

Answer (score 4):

Looks like someone [updated it for 1.9](https://github.com/cmcculloh/jQuery-UI-Tabs-Rotate)

Comment: +1 Was just writing the same thing ... link to jQuery UI docs here -> http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#removed-rotate-method